# Присвоить значение с помощью тернарной операции

Tags: python, python-3.x, условия

Как присвоить значение с помощью тернарной операции? Не совсем понял как это делается.

```
result = a if a > b else b
```

Надо, чтобы если `а` в диапазоне от 2 до 10, то присваивало `а`, но если выше 10 то `2`

Comment: И что присвоить, когда `a` ниже `2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = a if 2 <= a <= 10 else 2
```

Если **а** больше или равно 2 и меньше или равно 10 то присваиваем значение **а**, в остальных случаях присваиваем 2